# RestTemplate - object that contains collection

Tags: spring, resttemplate

I am having a problem using RestTemplate to retrieve a response from ombdapi. I have no problem reading this (getting 1 movie by id)
http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt0903624 but reading from a collection (while searching), I have no idea how to do: http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=hobbit

I believe the problem may be the *Search:* part, as this is not just an array (like in this example http://thespringway.info/spring-web/map-to-list-of-objects-from-json-array-with-resttemplate/ ). The following line is where the problem is:

```
ResponseEntity<OmdbMovie[]> responseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity("http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=" + title, OmdbMovie[].class);
```

and throws *Can not deserialize instance of ba.codecentric.excelimdb.OmdbMovie[] out of START_OBJECT token*

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse a similar structure to the JSON in http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=hobbit.

The result of the above url give:

1. an object: *starts with '{'*
2. with one attribute: *'Search'*
3. that has a collection of movies: *[{},{},...]*

For example you can write this class:

```
public class OmdbMovieList {
   private List<OmdbMovie> search;
   .....
}
```

and then use:

```
ResponseEntity<OmdbMovieList> responseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity("http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=" + title, OmdbMovieList.class);
```